# global name is not defined python

Tags: python

I get a NameError: global name 'valid_username' is not defined which confuses me. Why does that happen? I declared the valid_username function before actually calling it so what's the problem?

Here's the code full code:

```
import webapp2
import cgi
import re

class WelcomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Welcome, ")


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, username="", username_error="", password_error="", verify_password_error="", email="",
                   email_error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {
            "username": username, "username_error": username_error,
            "password_error": password_error,
            "verify_password_error": verify_password_error,
            "email": email, "email_error": email_error})

    def checkEscaped(text):
        return cgi.escape(text, quote="True")

    def valid_username(username):
        USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
        return USER_RE.match(checkEscaped(username))

    def valid_password(password):
        PASSWORD_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
        return PASSWORD_RE.match(checkEscaped(password))

    def valid_email(email):
        if len(email) > 0:
            EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
            return EMAIL_RE.match(checkEscaped(email))
        else:
            return True

    def password_match(password, confirmPassword):
        return password == confirmPassword

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        input_username = self.request.get('username')
        input_password = self.request.get('password')
        input_verify_password = self.request.get('verify_password')
        input_email = self.request.get('email')

        username_error = ""
        is_valid_name = valid_username(input_username)
        if not is_valid_name:
            username_error = "That's not a valid username."

        password_error = ""
        is_valid_password = valid_password(input_password)
        if not is_valid_password:
            password_error = "That wasn't a valid password."

        verify_password_error = ""
        is_valid_verify_password = password_match(input_password, input_verify_password)
        if not is_valid_verify_password:
            verify_password_error = "the passwords don't match"

        email_error = ""
        is_valid_email = valid_email(input_email)
        if not is_valid_email:
            email_error = "that's not a valid email"

        if not (is_valid_name and is_valid_password and is_valid_verify_password and is_valid_email):
            self.write_form(name, username_error, password_error, verify_password_error, email, email_error)
        else:
            self.redirect("/welcome")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage), ('/welcome', WelcomeHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference methods on the instance via the `self` object:

```
is_valid_password = self.valid_password(input_password)
```

You have the same problem in other places too; `checkEscaped()` should be `self.checkEscaped()`, `password_match()` should be `self.password_match()`,  etc.

Methods are not globals or locals.

Next, your methods should *accept* a `self` reference too; each of your own methods is missing the required parameter:

```
def checkEscaped(self, text):
    # ...

def valid_username(self, username):
    # ...

def valid_password(self, password):
    # ...

def valid_email(self, email):
    # ...

def password_match(self, password, confirmPassword):
    # ...
```

Of course, you could just move those four methods *out* of the class and actually make them global functions instead of methods. In that case, leave off the `self` arguments again.

Comment: And most of the OP code's method definitions are missing `self` args, too.

Comment: @PM2Ring yep, you're right. Coming from java - these function calls are implicit there

Comment: @nsmirosh: Fair enough. We do OOP a little differently in Python. But I'm sure you'll soon get the hang of it. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Why do you need to pass 'self' everywhere in functions?

Comment: @nsmirosh Take a look at [What is the purpose of self in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/4014959). Also [Why must ‘self’ be used explicitly in method definitions and calls?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls)

Comment: @nsmirosh: you only need those in *methods*, because that's how Python gives you access to the current instance.